# django many to many association

Tags: python, django

How do I create the association in MyListAssoc from here?
How would I delete it?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name)

class MyKeywords(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MyListAssoc(models.Model):    
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField(MyKeywords)

mygroup = Group.objects.get(name="mygroup")
mykeyword = MyKeywords.objects.create(name="mykeyword")
```

Comment: what you're doing doesn't make much sense. Do you want a group to have different keywords (foreign key)? or a group to have different keywords and a keyword to belong to different groups (many to many)?

Comment: Each group can have a list of different keywords and each keywords could belong to different groups

Comment: ok, so you just need a m2m relation, no `MyListAssoc`, see my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a many to many relation, something like:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(MyKeywords)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class MyKeywords(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Then, you can use your m2m relation:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name='something')
keyw = MyKeywords.objects.get(name='something_else')
group.keywords.add(keyw)
group.keywords.all()
group.keywords.remove(keyw)
```

**NOTE**: It is recommended that the name of a class is in singular, so it should be `MyKeyword` instead of `MyKeywords`

Comment: would performance be impacted by this, because my Group class actually has lots more field than im showing here

Comment: @user391986, no this is the only and right way to do it, read more about Django ORM. ManyToManyField would create a special database table to map this relations.

Comment: julio when I do Group.objects.get(name="something").keyword.all()   I get 'Group' object has no attribute 'keyword'

Comment: @user391986, if your using my code, I declared the attribute as `keywords`, is that it?

Answer (score 2):

```
mygroup = Group.objects.get(name="mygroup")
mykeyword = MyKeywords.objects.create(name="mykeyword")

mylistassoc = MyListAssoc(group=mygroup)
mylistassoc.save()
mylistassoc.keyword.add(mykeyword)
```

If you want to remove the association, just use `remove(mykeyword)` instead of `add(mykeyword)`.

However, you don't need intermediary model at all to set the relation between groups and keywords.

Comment: I don't get it, it's telling me  "'keyword' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: Oh, sorry, It's m2m, I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: Create your models like @julio-alegria [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075042/django-many-to-many-association/8075072#answer-8075175).

Comment: amazing! thanks so much! quick question  1. if you were to move the manytomany inside of group model would that affect performance and/or data redudancy or is the current design best (because my Group class actually has lots more field than im showing here)  2. how would you get name of all the keywords for a specific group

Comment: 1. No, it shouldn't be affected.

2. You get all keywords of a group doing: `group.keywords.all()`

Comment: No, this wont affect performance. By the way, you don't want to prematurely optimise the performance of your application. ["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" D. Knuth](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Program_optimization)